# OS not booting off of SSD

Tags: ssd, motherboard

I recently built a pc using the Maximus VIII Ranger motherboard and the Vector 180 SSD. For some reason, I cannot boot the OS off of the SSD. I have a hard drive as well, and that boots fine. My csm settings are UEFI (No AHCI). I can read and write to the SSD, though. How can I add UEFI to my SSD or AHCI to the motherboard?

TL;DR

SSD can read-write, but not boot

System Build

intel i7 6600k

corsair 750w psu

Maximus Viii ranger

Seagate 1tb HDD

Vector 180 SSD

EVGA gtx 970

Corsair h100i

Comment: How did you install the OS onto the SSD? Which OS is it?

Comment: I used a flash drive. It is windows 10 home, 64 bit

Comment: Did the Windows installer have issues seeing your SSD during the install process?